# What is the typical test automation scenario where decorator Design Pattern can be applied?

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, test-automation-framework, test-architecture

What is the typical automation scenario where [decorator design pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) can be applied in UI test automation ?

Please share your practical experiences with small code examples to help us fellow QA engineers.

**Decorator Design Pattern**: In object-oriented programming, the decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows behavior to be added to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class.[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) The decorator pattern is often useful for adhering to the Single Responsibility Principle, as it allows functionality to be divided between classes with unique areas of concern.

Comment: Interesting question but way too broad for canonical answer.  In my experience all of them can be applied but _it depends_ on the specific situation.

Comment: ... and you will use those patterns exactly for the same reason as they are used in "standard" programming. Test automation is writing programs, like any other programs they have a certain goal: test another program.

Comment: Narrowed down to one design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I use a 'decorate' like approach for Page Objects
I create an empty Page Object class
The I read a yaml file of name-locators
For each name-locator I dynamically add (like decorate) a method that will return the locator when passed the name
I can do this partly because I use Ruby which allows this.